# Jquery - замена параметров в img теге

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

**Есть HTML код:**

```
<h3 class="title"><a href="http://www.site.com/bla0">Title Test</a></h3>
<img width="550" height="550" src="http://www.site.com/images/image_test1-550x550.jpg" alt="Test Imgage 1" />

<h3 class="title"><a href="http://www.site.com/bla1">Title Test</a></h3>
<img width="550" height="550" src="http://www.site.com/images/image_test2-550x550.jpg" alt="Test Imgage 2" />
```

Задача.
Нужно при загрузке страницы, заменить в теге src текст 550x550 на 300x200
Далее нужно заменить ширину и высоту на 300 и 200

**Результат должен быть такой:**

```
<h3 class="title"><a href="http://www.site.com/bla0">Title Test</a></h3>
<img width="300" height="200" src="http://www.site.com/images/image_test1-300x200.jpg" alt="Test Imgage 1" />
```

Как я понимаю логика должна быть такова, мы находи класс title, потом ищем следующим за ним элемент img, находим его src и делаем замену.
Но как все это сделать при загрузке странице ? максимум что мне удалось сделать, это вот это

```
$('title').next().each(function() {
var test = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace("550x550","300x200");
alert(test);
});
```

Но как я понимаю евент должен отправлятся первей чем загрузится страница, что бы изображения уже подгружались с 300x200
даже ставил вместо var test, return, все равно не заменяет, вот тут не пойму почему (я только начал изучать js) очень интересно, но некоторые моменты не очень понятны.

Так же хотел бы знать нет ли у данного метода каких то подводных камней ? при работе с браузерами ?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Можно искать, используя [соседние селекторы](https://webref.ru/css/selector/adjacent).
2. Можно менять [несколько атрибутов сразу](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes).
3. Чтобы обойтись без метода `.each()`, можно вычислять новые значения атрибутов [колбэк-функцией](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#computed-attr-values). (Спасибо [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) за науку.)
4. Чтобы охватить несколько классов, добавьте селекторы с ними через запятую.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( '.title1+img,.title2+img,.title3+img' ).attr({
    src: function( i, val ) {
      return val.replace('550x550','300x200');
    },
    width: 300,
    height: 200
  });
});
```

```html
<h3 class="title1"><a href="http://www.site.com/bla1">Title 1</a></h3>
<img width="550" height="550" src="//placehold.it/550x550/936/fff/" alt="Image 1" />

<h3 class="title2"><a href="http://www.site.com/bla2">Title 2</a></h3>
<img width="550" height="550" src="//placehold.it/550x550/693/fff/" alt="Image 2" />

<h3 class="title3"><a href="http://www.site.com/bla3">Title 3</a></h3>
<img width="550" height="550" src="//placehold.it/550x550/369/fff/" alt="Image 3" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: тут each Тоже не нужен

Comment: @Grundy Поясните, пожалуйста, как без `each` прогнать `replace` по атрибуту каждого элемента в отдельности? У них же `src` разные...

Comment: [Например так](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) подходит и для объекта. Суть в том, что each уже скрыт в большинстве методов jquery и его нет нужды вызывать явно.

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо! Обновил ответ.

Comment: Хотел спросить, возможно ли делать замену в двух классах, со схожей структурой, но разными названиями классов, допустим, .title1 .title2. Вопрос возник из за того что я не хочу размножать код из за одного класса.

Comment: @webstackoverload Можно перечислить селекторы с несколькими классами через запятую. Обновил код в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Надо запускать при событии ready. В этот момент структура DOM уже сформирована, но еще никакие изображения не загружены.

Функция .replace заменяет текст в строке, но не в атрибутах. Надо получить сначала атрибут src в строку, преобразовать ее, а потом записать назад, указав *вторым* аргументом в .attr().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.title').next().each(function() {
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    src = src.replace("550x550","300x200");
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', src);
  });
});
```

Comment: Cпасибо за развернутый ответ, логику понял. Это главное, просто не мог понять как обратно вставить из переменной с результатом обратно в src. Я просто равнялся на один пример, который сразу находит класс (дива) а в нем элемент src, и потом по return заменяет его аттрибут, кода две строчки, думал сдесь можно провернуть тоже самое, но видать нет, так как тут идет поиск второго элемента.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, я бы и не заметил ее если бы не сказали. :)

Comment: Да, не очень видна галка. Я обычно новым пользователям потому и напоминаю.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky да можно было и не удалять )

Comment: each не нужен, два раза find не нужен

Comment: Я понимаю. Копировал у ТС. Моей задачей было с помощью минимальных изменений его кода показать суть ошибок.

Comment: @Grundy Так-то если код сравнивать, Глеб гораздо лучше моего написал.

Comment: это не мешает улучшить твой ответ